# Reuse Where Condition throughout Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have created one stored procedure, which returns records from multiple select queries.

See the below query:

```
DECLARE @UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '96105876-AB55-4D28-A8DD-6BFEC9D38EF8'

SELECT 
    CD.[Name],
    CD.[ASIN],
    CD.[Category],
    CD.[Quantity],
    CD.[Total],
    CD.[Weight]
FROM CartDetails CD
INNER JOIN Cart C ON C.Id = CD.CartId 
INNER JOIN Users U ON U.Id = C.UserId
WHERE U.Id = @UserId AND U.Active = 1 AND U.Deleted = 0

SELECT  
    DCC.DiscountAmount, 
    DCC.DiscountCouponId
FROM DiscountCouponConsumed DCC
INNER JOIN Users U ON U.Id = DCC.UserId
WHERE U.Id = @UserId AND U.Active = 1 AND U.Deleted = 0
```

Here, I have written the same query (which is always remains the same) in where condition. Now my question is, can we write `where` query once and will used for each select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have individual select statements with no relation between them then this might help you . Prepare your select queries and Where queries in separate variables and concatenate them together before you execute it .

```
DECLARE @UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '96105876-AB55-4D28-A8DD-6BFEC9D38EF8'

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) , @SelectQuery NVARCHAR(MAX), @WhereQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @WhereQuery = 'WHERE U.Id = @UserId AND U.Active = 1 AND U.Deleted = 0'

 -- Query 1 

SET @SelectQuery =
'SELECT 
    CD.[Name],
    CD.[ASIN],
    CD.[Category],
    CD.[Quantity],
    CD.[Total],
    CD.[Weight]
FROM CartDetails CD
INNER JOIN Cart C ON C.Id = CD.CartId 
INNER JOIN Users U ON U.Id = C.UserId'

SET @Query = @SelectQuery + @WhereQuery

EXEC (@Query)


--- Query 2

SET @Query = NULL 

SET @SelectQuery = NULL

SET @SelectQuery ='
SELECT  
    DCC.DiscountAmount, 
    DCC.DiscountCouponId
FROM DiscountCouponConsumed DCC
INNER JOIN Users U ON U.Id = DCC.UserId '

SET @Query = @SelectQuery + @WhereQuery

EXEC (@Query)
```

Comment: @AkhataraliAnsari Welcome :)

Comment: Using a dynamic SQL query is really an overkill here in my opinion. If you're always filtering on `Users` record this way, just run a query to check if the user is Active and is not Deleted at the beginning of your stored procedure, and if it doesn't meet your conditions, reset @UserId to NULL so that no other query will yield results. Dynamic SQL is very hard to maintain and even harder to debug once something goes wrong.

Comment: @MarcinJ +1 for simplicity! In fact you should add it as an answer - it might help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the valid User ID's in a temp table which is populated according to your common `where` clause. You can extend this method to as many queries as you like.

```
DECLARE @UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '96105876-AB55-4D28-A8DD-6BFEC9D38EF8';

declare @User table (id uniqueidentifier);

insert into @User (id)
  select id
  from Users U
  where U.Id = @UserId AND U.Active = 1 AND U.Deleted = 0;

SELECT 
    CD.[Name],
    CD.[ASIN],
    CD.[Category],
    CD.[Quantity],
    CD.[Total],
    CD.[Weight]
FROM CartDetails CD
INNER JOIN Cart C ON C.Id = CD.CartId 
INNER JOIN Users U ON U.Id = C.UserId
--WHERE U.Id = @UserId AND U.Active = 1 AND U.Deleted = 0
where U.id in (select id from @User);

SELECT  
  DCC.DiscountAmount,
  DCC.DiscountCouponId
FROM DiscountCouponConsumed DCC
INNER JOIN Users U ON U.Id = DCC.UserId
--WHERE U.Id = @UserId AND U.Active = 1 AND U.Deleted = 0
where U.id in (select id from @User);
```

Comment: This is also a valid way, but I have to execute one more select query for this. Thanks for your replay.

Comment: Yes, that is also a good point, that we can't find issue easily, it will take time to resolve the issue.

Comment: This is not the answer to his question. What he's asking here is to reuse where condition.

Comment: @KinjalParmar this does in fact reuse the where clause, and without using dynamic SQL as well. If a change is made to the conditions which determine a valid user, all queries will be updates, just as the OP requires.

Answer (score 0):

Close to Dales answer, but joining @Users.

```
DECLARE @UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '96105876-AB55-4D28-A8DD-6BFEC9D38EF8';

DECLARE @Users TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    Active BIT,
    Deleted BIT
);

INSERT INTO @Users
(
    Id,
    Active,
    Deleted
)
SELECT Id,
       Active,
       Deleted
FROM Users
WHERE U.Id = @UserId
      AND U.Active = 1
      AND U.Deleted = 0;

SELECT CD.Name,
       CD.ASIN,
       CD.Category,
       CD.Quantity,
       CD.Total,
       CD.Weight
FROM CartDetails CD
    INNER JOIN Cart C
        ON C.Id = CD.CartId
    INNER JOIN @Users U
        ON U.Id = C.UserId;

SELECT DCC.DiscountAmount,
       DCC.DiscountCouponId
FROM DiscountCouponConsumed DCC
    INNER JOIN @Users U
        ON U.Id = DCC.UserId;
```

Answer (score 0):

@MarcinJ provided the simplest answer in a comment which I think is worthy of being an answer.

> If you're always filtering on Users record this way, just run a query
>   to check if the user is Active and is not Deleted at the beginning of
>   your stored procedure, and if it doesn't meet your conditions, reset
>   @UserId to NULL so that no other query will yield results

i.e. have the following code at the top of the proc:

```
select @UserId = case when exists (
    select 1
    from Users U
    where U.Id = @UserId AND U.Active = 1 AND U.Deleted = 0
  ) then @UserId else null end;
```